# ASP.NET Core Entity Framework insert fail but sometimes pass

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core

I know this question might have been asked several times, but I tried quite a bunch of solution but doesn't works well, so I think maybe I should have a post to see if anyone has idea.

I have some entity class similar as below. Which `StockMain` create the Guid and will be used in `StockAttributeDetail` table. `StockAttributeDetail` has a primary key set of `MainId + AttributeName + InsertedTime`.

```
public class StockAttributeDetail
{
    public Guid MainId { get; set; }
    public string AttributeName { get; set; }
    public string AttributeValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime InsertedTime { get; set; }
}

public class StockMain
{
    public Guid MainId { get; set; }
    public string StockID { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public DateTime InsertedTime { get; set; }
}
```

So at first my function will query the desired `StockID` with latest `InsertedTime` to get the `MainId` from `StockMain` (`StockID` might be duplicate, so select the last one only). And use `MainId` to query `StockAttributeDetail` table for the attributes belong to this `MainId`.

```
public void DoSth(string StockID)
{
    using(var db = new StockDbContext())
    {
        var key = (from stock in db.Table_StockMain
                   where stock.StockID == StockID
                   select stock)
                  .OrderByDescending(o => o.InsertedTime)
                  .FirstOrDefault();
        
        var stockAttrs = db.Table_StockAttributeDetail
                           .Where(c => c.MainId == key.MainId)
                           .ToList();
            
        List<StockAttributeDetail> attrsToAdd = new List<StockAttributeDetail>();
        /* Do something to define to define a set of new attributes to add. It's a bit too long so I chop off.
            This part only use stockAttrs as comparison but never change any value on it.
        */
            
        foreach(var attr in attrsToAdd)
        {
            /* This if statement is the one that insert sometimes success sometimes failed.
            if (!stockAttrs.Any(e => e.AttributeName == attr.AttributeName && e.AttributeValue == attr.AttributeValue)
            */
            if (!db.Table_StockAttributeDetail
                   .Any(e => e.AttributeName == attr.AttributeName && 
                             e.AttributeValue == attr.AttributeValue && 
                             e.MainId == key.MainId))
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1);
                attr.InsertedTime = DateTime.Now; 
                // Because AttributeDetail use InsertedTime as part of primary Key, so in order to insert a possible same name attribute, we shift the time.
                db.Table_StockAttributeDetail.Add(attr);
            }
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

So the tricky parts comes for following statement

If I use following if statement by reusing the stockAttrs I queried before. Sometimes `SaveChanges` will succeed, sometimes it fails. And the fail reason is cannot insert duplicate key in Object even if I already shift the time by 1ms.

```
if(!stockAttrs.Any(e => e.AttributeName == attr.AttributeName && e.AttributeValue == attr.AttributeValue)
```

However if I use this if statement, everything will be fine, the only problem is if I have 10 attributes to add, every time it goes back to DB and check, it might take 0.1 ~ 0.2 secs, and will end up causing extra transaction time.

```
if(!db.Table_StockAttributeDetail
                    .Any(e => e.AttributeName == attr.AttributeName && e.AttributeValue == attr.AttributeValue && e.MainId == key.MainId))
```

Anyone have idea why EF sometimes success, sometimes fail on the first if but always success on second statement.

**UPDATE**
By taking the suggestion from comment. Using Transaction, things went well. So I think when doing stuff like insert or update, a transaction is safer.

Comment: Terrible working with database. Add transaction and remove `Thread.Sleep`. Without transaction there is possibility that other thread can insert duplicate. With pure EF you cannot achieve good performance in such case. If you add ommited code maybe some new possibilities will be uncovered.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Thanks, actually you got exactly the answer, after I add a transaction before the function start insert, everything works fine.